# How to create the HttpWebRequest https://xxx/1/Response?format=json&body={"operation":"list"}

Tags: c#, web-services, httpwebrequest, system.net.httpwebrequest

How can I create the HttpWebrequest for this URL:

```
https://xxx/1/Response?format=json&body={"operation":"list"}?
```

I am not able to create it as there is a string in the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all `"` with `\"`

```
https://xxx/1/Response?format=json&body={\“operation\”:\“list\”}
```

for more advanced help please show us your code that is not working

Comment: @Santhosh did this fix your issue?

Comment: Thanks you so much for a look at this post.